# How to access values of fields from base class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I want to access fields of a class from base class in Java. I can do it in dot net.
see the example:

```
public class a{

// here I want to read the value of name or f1 or f2 or every other field values from derived classes
}
public class b extends a{
  public string name;
}
public class c extends a{
  public string f1;
  public string f2;
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: Don't do it. The super class is not supposed to know base classes attributes. You seem to have a design flaw.

Comment: Flow is like water, should be `------ >`  not like  `<--------`

Comment: Short answer: You cannot. For a better answer, please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: If this can be done in C# (?), it is rather scary...

Comment: @Thilo That is factually incorrect. It is possible (see Marko's answer), but it also nullifies the purpose of having sub classes.

Comment: @Torben: It was the short answer :-) (And since Marko's answer involves a type cast to the subclass, it is not really the parent class doing the accessing, it is just the normal public access available to anywhere -- and the option will go away if the field is no longer public).

Comment: Man I did it an the dot net framework before. what I want to do is to create a class for creating database methods like insert or select.
I want the top class know the fields from derived class and prepare proper insert command for it.
I can even read the field names in this way but can read the values.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot read the fields your class doesn't own without explicitly naming the subclass. So, this is doable as follows:

```
((c)this).f1;
```

However, doing this would be a bad code smell: you are now tying an abstraction embodied by `a` to one of its specific implementations/extensions. You should better rethink your design.

#### An important note on code conventions

In Java it is a must that you name your classes using CamelCase and packages using lowercase, otherwise some quite bad name-resolution anomalies can happen. Not to mention any Java user getting totally lost reading your code.

Comment: Can not emphasize the "You should better rethink your design"-part enough.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't want to do that as it defeats the idea of inheritance.

You can, however set up abstract functions that are implemented by derived classes. That's good programming style. Those functions can access member data in the derived and base classes.

Doing things like (i) using reflection and(ii) casting to derived classes are hacks and should be avoided. The reason being that changing a derived class should not trigger the necessity for changes in a base class.

Comment: I can read the field names in this way but can read the values.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do in this case is to define abstract methods in your class a, which class b and c has to implement. You can then call these methods from a to obtain the values set by b and c.

```
public abstract class a{

// here I want to read the value of name or f1 or f2 or every other field values from derived classes
    abstract String getName();
    abstract String getF1();
    abstract String getF2();
}

public class b extends a{
  private String name;

  @Override
  public String getName() { return name; } 

  @Override
  public String getF1() { return null; }

  @Override
  public String getF2() { return null; }
}

public class c extends a{
  public String f1;
  public String f2;


  @Override
  public String getName() { return null; } 

  @Override
  public String getF1() { return f1; }

  @Override
  public String getF2() { return f2; }
}
```

Comment: That's not a great solution either. Now *all* subclasses have to know about all other subclasses' fields.

Comment: @Thilo True, but considering OP's initial code example, I don't think we can avoid it. Having a super class with two seemingly different and unrelated sub classes is not a good idea. We would have to know more about what OP wants to achieve.

Comment: Yes, we need to know what OP really wants to do.

Comment: Considering the OP original request, I see this as the most straight forward and understandable solution. However, I completely agree that its not a great solution and the OPs original design should possibly be reconsidered.

Comment: Man I did it an the dot net framework before. what I want to do is to create a class for creating database methods like insert or select.
I want the top class know the fields from derived class and prepare proper insert command for it.
I can even read the field names in this way but can read the values.

Comment: @EhsanShirzadi Sounds to me like inheritance is not what you want here. What you should do is create a separate class for your insert and create statements (either a class that simply generates the queries, or one that executes them), and it's method should take your domain objects as parameters.