# How to access field values of a derived class from it's base class in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection

I want to access fields of a derived class from it's base class in java without knowing the name of fields.
For what purpose?
I want to have a "table" class to manage database tables like INSERT,UPDATE.
I a derived class to have only fields and values, and in the base class I read that fields and values and create proper INSERT or UPDATE commands.

I can do this in C# this way:

```
for (int count = 0; count < finfo.Length; count++)
{
    value = finfo[count].GetValue(this);
    name = finfo[count].Name;
}
```

I can read field names and type in java like this:

```
for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
    name = f.getName();
}
```

but I don't know how to read the VALUE of that field!

I'm asking this question in different ways in many forums but I'm getting no answer! 
Please help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you so insistent on doing all of this by hand instead of just using JPA?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access values of fields from base class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136906/how-to-access-values-of-fields-from-base-class)

Answer (score 5):

Given a `Field f` you can read the value of that field in a particular object using `f.get(object)`

```
for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
    name = f.getName();
    value = f.get(this);
}
```

`get` returns `Object` - if the field is of a primitive type (`boolean`, `char`, `int`, etc.) then the corresponding wrapper (`Boolean`, `Character`, `Integer`, ...) will be returned (or you can use the type-specific `getBoolean`, `getChar`, etc. methods to return the primitive type directly).  The `get` method can throw various exceptions (some checked and some unchecked) which you'll have to handle appropriately, see the JavaDoc for details.

But to step back from your specific question, if your goal is to map classes to database tables then there are mature, well-tested frameworks that can do all the hard work for you, such as [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) or one of the many implementations of JPA, and I would strongly recommend you look into one or more of those before you try and roll your own.

Comment: There is no f.get(this);
when I typed this, it's underlined with this error:
Unhandled exception type IllegalAccessException
Should I import something?

Comment: @EhsanShirzadi as with any Java code that can throw checked exceptions you will have to add whatever handling is appropriate to your situation (try/catch blocks or a `throws` declaration, for example).

Answer (score 0):

In your base class, which will be declared as abstract, you can declare an abstract method that will get the values

```
public abstract BaseClass{
    protected abstract FieldInfo getFieldInfo(i);

    public void doSomething(){
        for (int count = 0; count < finfo.Length; count++)
        {
            FieldInfo finfo = getFieldInfo(count);
            value = finfo.GetValue(this);
            name = finfo.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your InheritedClass you will have to implement it.

Comment: Man your solution is in C#, I need java solution!